# Internel Sever Error and .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework, tortoisesvn

I import a project via tortoise-svn to inside my wamp server's www folder.

but I got

> **Internel Sever Error**

in apache error log>

> [Fri Aug 24 11:04:45 2012] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1]
>   C:/wamp/www/Myproject/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps
>   misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server
>   configuration, referer:http://localhost/

**this may not affect to that:** that project use zend, i set include_path in php.ini file like this

> include_path =
>   ".;c:\php\includes;C:\wamp\www\ZendFramework-1.11.12\library\Zend"

but that project already have zend inside library folder.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this is uncommented in your apache config:

```
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
```

The `Header` directive is part of mod_headers. Without that module loaded it's going to throw an error.

Comment: thnkz, uncommented that line bt now I got this> 

Not Found

The requested URL /public/ was not found on this server.

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=290304000, public"
</FilesMatch>
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</ifmodule>

Comment: @Nash can you please post that in your original question (and add the 4 spaces in front of each line so the site formats it as code)? because it's gibberish inside a comment